# JS DOM uma função básica

Tags: javascript, dom

the object calls this function, as usual. What happens? The function take this third parameter, which should change an attribute of the object, what not procced. Anybody could enlight?

```js
  function insertbean(post_id, ip, imgcgn) {

     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("bn"+post_id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  request.open("GET", "incrbean.php?postid="+post_id+"&ip="+ip, true);
  request.send();

      if(imgcgn){
              document.getElementById("lmp"+post_id).src = "SVG/lampsmall.svg";
              document.getElementById("lmp"+post_id).onclick = "insertbean("+post_id+", "+ip+", false)";
            
      }
      else {
              document.getElementById("lmp"+post_id).src = "SVG/lamponsmall.svg";
              document.getElementById("lmp"+post_id).onclick = "insertbean("+post_id+", "+ip+", true)";

    }
```

```html
<button onclick="insertbean($post_id, $ip, true)">Clickme!</button>
```

Seemly everything is right, the files just exists in the folder and so on, that's why i'm so curious to know.

THanks.

Comment: First step would be to [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) like these, they have way too many problems to be worth using nowadays, such as a demented scope chain and quote escaping issues. Attach event listeners properly using Javascript with `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Yes, the whole one is most complex. Tks

Comment: `Element.onevent` IDL properties do not accept strings, only the attribute does, but as has been said, that's bad anyway. You'll want to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the arguments to your function.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're attempting, but here's what is happening here:

On click, you are passing 1 parameter: `true`. You are not passing a second parameter, so it will always come through as `undefined`.

So in the function, you are passing `true` into `post_id`. `undefined` is falsey, so it will go to the else statement.

Then, `"lmp" + post_id` will give you what is very likely a nonsense string when adding a boolean to this string: `"lmptrue"`. I think that will not match the id of anything on your page, so nothing will happen.